# How do I globally install a node-cli tool with es6 import support?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I am creating a simple project-generator tool and I am using es6 imports in my main `index.js` file. I have a `babel-node` installed with a `.babelrc` at the root of my project.

To install the tool globally I have this in my `package.json`:

```
"bin": {
  "generate": "./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./index.js"
},
```

When I run `npm link` or `npm install -g` at the root of my project, I get the error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-project-generator/node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./index.js'
```

I have also tried:

```
"bin": {
  "generate": "babel-node ./index.js"
},
```

and

```
"bin": {
  "generate": "npx babel-node ./index.js"
},
```

This tool is working just fine in the context of my project. So how do I add es6 support to install it globally?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `babel-node` as a dependency to your package?

Anyway, the more proper way of doing it is to compile your program with babel into some `dist` directory in advance so that it can be run without any additional pre-processor.

```js
"bin": {
  "generate": "./dist/index.js"
}
```

Less problematic and faster command execution.

Comment: interesting. I will try this